# How to get 'last Monday' on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

With BigQuery, I need to find out when was "last Monday". How can I calculate this date?

For example, today is Monday, so the formula should return today's date if called. Yesterday it should have returned the 27th of last month.

Based on https://blog.svpino.com/2015/08/03/how-to-determine-last-mondays-date-in-bigquery

Answer (score 19):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY))
```

Comment: In addition, if you wanted to get the previous Monday on the day of Monday:

WITH lastMonday as (
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) = 2 THEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) ELSE CURRENT_DATE() END AS d
)
SELECT DATE_TRUNC((SELECT d FROM lastMonday), WEEK(MONDAY))

Answer (score 2):

As Santiago Pino [published on his blog](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/08/03/how-to-determine-last-mondays-date-in-bigquery):

```
select 
    date(date_add(current_date(), 
    if(dayofweek(current_date()) = 1, 
        -6, 
        -(dayofweek(current_date()) - 2)), 
    "DAY"))
```

(copied [with permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHRTu.png))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK function:

```
Select 
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC( UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK(NOW(), 1), "%Y-%m-%d" )
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers by @Felipe Hoffa and @YABADABADOU are in the old `legacy SQL`. Here's an answer in the `standard SQL` (which is very similar to Felipe Hoffa's answer):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 
             INTERVAL 
             IF( EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) = 1, 
                 6, 
                 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2) 
             DAY);
```